# Display 'references' instead of 'bibliography' while using polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I recently moved from `babel` to `polyglossia` because in my thesis I am using English, Sanskrit and Kannada as equally weighted primary languages.

When I use the command `\printbibliography{}`, it headlines the section as "Bibliography" instead of "References".

Is there any way to get it to say "References" instead? My university insists upon it.

I am aware of various solutions published on this stack  similar to this

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
```

but they probably apply only to babel as they have no effect on my document.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can stick to `babel` if you want, because it supports these three languages.

Comment: `\printbibliography[title=References]` should work.

Comment: @JavierBezos this is true indeed. Did not realize babel can do non latin languages/scripts. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default title for the bibliography in an `article`-like class is "References", in a `report`/`book`-like class it is "Bibliography". These names are stored in `\refname` and `\bibname`, respectively.

It is a bit tricky to overwrite `\refname` and `\bibname` directly, since both `biblatex` and `polyglossia`/`babel` redefine these strings when the language is changed. That means that a change you make may be made undone at begin document (when the document language is set up) or whenever languages are switched.

---

With a current version of `biblatex` the prettiest solution probably uses `\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{title=\refname}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: References]

---

But for a one-off you could just use

```
\printbibliography[title=\refname]
```

instead of `\printbibliography`

---

In `biblatex` contexts, `biblatex` controls `\bibname` and uses its bibstring `bibliography` for that, so

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  bibliography = {References},
}
```

would also work.

Comment: Wow this is an amazingly detailed answer! Thank you so much.
I never really learned latex the way one would learn a programming language. Just figured it out as I went along. 
Your response helps me tremendously in understanding whats going on.
For now I will start with `\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{title=\refname}`

Thanks again!

Comment: @RanjithHegde If the answer helped you resolve your question, you may want to accept it to signal to other people that the question is answered. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers